# RaspberryPi camera rev 1.3 cross section

Tags: camera

I want to modify the RaspberryPi camera rev 1.3 by cutting out the camera chip. Is there some documentation availiable for example a detailed cross section picture? So I know where to exactly cut without destroying the chip.

Comment: adafruit actually produce a mini(spy) camera for the Pi that may avoid you cutting down an existing one, depending on your requirements. http://www.adafruit.com/products/1937

Answer (score 1):

I found one, for all of those who are searching too. I had to type in the exacte type designation:
[image]